# How to write a subdomain with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I am trying to make a subdomain forward through the htaccess document. The below instructions will forward `http://sub.domain.com` to the internal structure `Root > subfolder > index.php`. This all works well.

```
# REWRITE DEFAULTS
# ====================================================================================================
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# SUBDOMAIN FORWARD
# ====================================================================================================
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
```

There is only one (big) downfall with this method. When you try to reach a folder within the subfolder such as `Root > subfolder > images` by going to `http://sub.domain.com/images/` then all works well again, **however** when you don't end it with a slash `http://sub.domain.com/images` the url in the address bar will become `http://sub.domain.com/subfolder/images/` which is clearly not what I want.

So what if I would add a slash if a slash was forgotten?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

This all works when you have a normal URL (`http://www.domain.com/images`), because it will detect it is a directory and adds a slash and if it's a file it will omit the slash. However this does not work for our `http://sub.domain.com/images` example.

**Does anyone have an idea how you can make subdomains work properly using htaccess?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because `/subfolder/images` is a real directory and `mod_dir` module adds a trailing slash to all directories by doing a 301 redirect.

You can use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add a trailing slash if /subfolder/images is a directory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/$1/ -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```